# Discovering the NullabilityInfo of a generic parameter?

Tags: c#, reflection, nullable-reference-types

I have successfully read and used the NullableAttribute/NullableContextAttribute (based on https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/main/docs/features/nullable-metadata.md and too much trial and errors) for properties, fields and method parameters.

However, I'm failing to analyze the nullabilities of a generic parameter. My goal is to obtain the nullability information of the IA type parameter (the tuple):

```cs
interface ICommand<T> { }

interface IA : ICommand<(string,List<string?>?)> { }
```

However, the Nullable and NullableContext attributes are clearly not enough. The code below dumps these attributes on the type tree:

```cs
        [Test]
        public void type_in_generic_definition()
        {
            var b = new StringBuilder();
            Dump( typeof( IA ), b, Environment.NewLine );
            Dump( typeof( IA ).GetInterfaces()[0], b, Environment.NewLine );
            Console.WriteLine( b );
        }

        void Dump( Type type, StringBuilder w, string newline )
        {
            newline = newline + "  ";
            w.Append( type.Name ).Append( newline );
            var p = GetNullableProfile( type );
            w.Append( $"Nullable: {(p != null ? string.Join( null, p.Select( v => v.ToString() ) ) : "null")}" ).Append( newline );
            var c = GetNullableContextValue( type );
            w.Append( $"NullableContext: {(c != null ? c.ToString() : "null")}" ).Append( newline );
            var d = GetNullableContextValueFromDeclaringType( type );
            w.Append( $"NullableContext (DeclaringType): {(d != null ? d.ToString() : "null")}" ).Append( newline );
            if( type.IsGenericType )
            {
                foreach( var sub in type.GetGenericArguments() )
                {
                    Dump( sub, w, newline );
                }
            }
            newline = newline.Substring( 0, newline.Length - 2 );
            w.Append( newline );
        }

        byte[]? GetNullableProfile( Type t )
        {
            var a = t.CustomAttributes.FirstOrDefault( a => a.AttributeType.Name == "NullableAttribute" && a.AttributeType.Namespace == "System.Runtime.CompilerServices" );
            if( a == null ) return null;
            object? data = a.ConstructorArguments[0].Value;
            Debug.Assert( data != null );
            if( data is byte b ) return new[] { b };
            return ((IEnumerable<CustomAttributeTypedArgument>)data).Select( a => (byte)a.Value! ).ToArray();
        }

        byte? GetNullableContextValue( Type t )
        {
            var a = t.CustomAttributes.FirstOrDefault( a => a.AttributeType.Name == "NullableContextAttribute" && a.AttributeType.Namespace == "System.Runtime.CompilerServices" );
            return a == null
                    ? null
                    : (byte)a.ConstructorArguments[0].Value!;
        }

        byte? GetNullableContextValueFromDeclaringType( Type t )
        {
            var parent = t.DeclaringType;
            while( parent != null )
            {
                var found = GetNullableContextValue( parent );
                if( found.HasValue ) return found;
                parent = parent.DeclaringType;
            }
            return null;
        }
```

This gives me this description that doesn't make any sense (at least to me) regarding the actual nullabilities of `(string,List<string?>?)` (I've commented the lines after the //).

```
    IA
      Nullable: null
      NullableContext: null
      NullableContext (DeclaringType): 1       // I'm working in a NRT aware context where 
                                               // reference types are by default not annotated
                                               // (not null). Ok.
      
    ICommand`1
      Nullable: null
      NullableContext: 2                       // Q0: On what scope does this apply?
      NullableContext (DeclaringType): 1       // Ok. It's my context.
      ValueTuple`2                             
        Nullable: null                         // Ouch! I was expecting a "122" here :(
        NullableContext: null
        NullableContext (DeclaringType): null
        String
          Nullable: 0                           // Q1: Explicit oblivious here. Was expecting 1!
          NullableContext: 1                    // Q2: Scope? Is it the 1 I'm after?
          NullableContext (DeclaringType): null
          
        List`1
          Nullable: 0                           // The same as the string!
          NullableContext: 1                    // But the list IS nullable!
          NullableContext (DeclaringType): null
          String
            Nullable: 0                            // The inner string is nullable :(
            NullableContext: 1
            NullableContext (DeclaringType): null
```

Where should I look for this? What did I miss?

Comment: It seems the custom attribute you are looking for is attached to a `InterfaceImpl` Metadata entry. Afaik there is no option to use the .Net framework reflection API to read from this table. From this post https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/30570 i think the .Net Core `System.Reflection.Metadata.Metadatareader` API may be able to read custom attributes from the `InterfaceImpl` table.

Comment: Ouch! Thanks! This makes perfect sense. I'll have a look to that. Thanks again.

Answer (score -1):

The `Nullable` and `NullableContext` [attributes](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/main/docs/features/nullable-metadata.md) are *for compiler use only*, this means that in order to use these attributes, at least in *in any meaningful way* would be if you were programming with roslyn source(aka. programming a/the compiler itself).

### If you are not programming the compiler

Remeber that nullability is *almost* strictly a compiler time concept. This means it basically just exists so the compiler can determine through heuristics and other magic that **you** are using types in a way that would prevent `NullReferenceExceptions` during runtime, among other benefits like readability etc.

That's not to say we *cant* figure out if a type is `Nullable<>` at runtime. For this we have to remember a couple a rules on how `Nullable<>` works.

[Nullable Types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/types#nullable-types) are a `struct` with an underlying non-nullable type(`Nullable<>.Value`). The underlying type of a `Nullable<T>` *cannot* be a nullable type or a reference type.

So at runtime, to determine if any given type is `Nullable<>` or not we just have to check to see if we can extract the underlying type.

```cs
byte? GetNullableContextValue(Type t)
{
    // if it's a struct, and it's a Nullable<> then we will be able to extract the underlying type
    if (Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(t) != null)
    {
        return 1;
    }

    // the type was a class, object, or struct not wrapped in a Nullable<>
    return 0;
}
```

What this means is that a class *can not* be wrapped in a `Nullable<>` struct. That may seem pretty counter-intuitive because there is nothing stopping you from using `CustomClass? variable = GetPossiblyNullCustomClass();` in your source code.

The reason why it will still let you do this is for a couple of reasons, but mainly one, so the compiler can effectively track the path of objects in your source code and notify you of possible null reference exceptions that may occur(say if you have forgotten to initialize a variable, among many other kinds of heuristic checks). After those compile-time checks are done and the source is compiled any `CustomClass?` are ignored, and `CustomClass` is used instead.

I'm sure there is some really cool hacky way to find it, but at runtime with reflection I don't *believe* there is a way to determine if some `class` is a `class?`.

### If you **are** programming Rosyln

Make sure you have access to `System.Runtime.CompilerServices` within your scope, you would do this by importing the source for the roslyn compiler and adding a reference to it in your project. To access the nullability flag simply access it directly on the attribute through reflection here's a short example of how you might do that:

```cs
NullableContextAttribute? foundAttribute = type.GetCustomAttribute<NullableContextAttribute>();

switch(foundAttribute.Flag)
{
    case 0:
    case 1:
    case 2:
        // do work;
        break;
    default:
        throw new Exception("Flag out of bounds.");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but actually I known all of this (as I said, I successfully managed to analyze Fields/Props/Method parameters). FYI, Roselyn is not needed since FullName is enough.